# WPF: ItemsControl.Resources Setter - binding to element's content

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, itemscontrol

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={Problem}, Path=Content}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>

    <RadioButton Content="1"/>
    <RadioButton Content="2"/>
    <RadioButton Content="3"/>
    <RadioButton Content="4"/>
    <RadioButton Content="5"/>
    <RadioButton Content="6"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

I want to set the CommandParameter of every RadioButton to it's Content. 
Which RelativeSource should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it to be correct without setting RelativeSource. But if it's not, you can try following construction - `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type RadioButton}}`